# big data base problems using clasic pivot table in excel

Tags: excel, bigdata, excel-2010, pivot-table

If I've a data base of 600M lines in excel and everytime i try to use a pivot table in clasic mode excel just broke, now I'm trying to split the data in 4 or 5, but don't know how to combine the data in one pivot table so I'd filter it with a common characteristic

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: if the max rows in excel is 1048576 then that is a lot of workbooks...